# where is the actual code for the XNA "game loop"?

Tags: xna

I am beginner trying to learn `C#` and `XNA`. I am trying to get a deeper understanding of the XNA game loop.

Although there are plenty of articles explaining what the game loop is, I can't seem to find the actual loop implementation anywhere.

The closest I think I have gone to finding the loop is this member of the game class in the `MSDN` documentation:

```
public void Tick ()
```

If this is the correct one, where can I find the inner implementation of this method to see how it calls the Update and Draw methods, or is that not possible?

Comment: It will be a callback from the graphics driver. I'm not sure how many layers there are between XNAs update() and the callback. This is not required knowledge for learning c# and XNA. The whole point of XNA is that all that is hidden under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

Monogame is an open source replica of XNA based on modern rendering pipelines, and SharpDX.Toolkit implements a very XNA-Like interface for DX11 (Monogame actually uses SharpDX under the hood for DirectX integration)... you can probably find the game loop in the source code from either of those projects and it will likely be be close to if not identical to what MS XNA actually uses.

That being said, the game loop actually doesn't do much for simple demo applications (they tend to pile up everything in a single method to update/render a simple scene), though in full games with component based scene graphs it can get a little complicated. For single threaded engines, the general idea is to:

```
    1. update the state of any inputs, 
    2. process any physics simulation if needed, 
    3. call update on all the updatable objects in 
       your scene graph (the engine I'm working on 
       uses interfaces to avoid making wasteful calls 
       on empty stub methods), 
    4. clear the working viewport/depth buffers, 
    5. call render on each renderable object to actually 
       get the GPU drawing on the back buffer. 
    6. swap the render buffers putting everything just 
       drawn to the back buffer up on screen, and making 
       the old viewport buffer the new back buffer to be 
       cleared and drawn on the next rendering pass.
    7. start over at step 1 :)
```

That pretty much covers the basics and should generally apply no matter what underlying API or engine you are working with.

Comment: Where exactly does the OP mention `Monogame`?

Comment: He asked for source code to a game loop implementation similar to what XNA uses and I named 2 open source projects that are XNA-Like and implement game loops

Answer (score 0):

Since `XNA` is closed-sourced, it is not possible to see the code for the game loop, as defined in the `Game` class.  The `Tick()` you have referenced is not exposed nor referenced in any `XNA` documentation(Although, it may be used behind the scenes, I do not know).

As @Ascendion has pointed out, `MonoGame` has an equivalent class named `Game` see [here](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Game.cs).  While, this may not reflect the `XNA` code exactly, it is the best compatible source (all tests performed between the two, they return the same values), that we the public, have available.

The main side effect to the `MonoGame` implementation is the platform independent code, which may be hard to comprehend, since some of the implementation code is located in additional files. It is not hard to trace the sources back to the expected platform source code.

This post is to serve as a clarification to all who may stumble upon this later.